# c# getting files form directory

Tags: c#, file, directory

i have problem with my c# code, i want to list all files from mozilla user data folder, i was trying to do it with:

```
String dir = Directory.GetDirectories(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\")[0];
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppData") + "\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\" + dir);
```

But when i execute this code i get error that tells me that format of this path is not supported. In error info i can see that my path is:

"C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\4wrivbme.default"

Its because of \? I'm sure that i need this.

Answer (score 3):

If I have understood correctly your code, then the second line should be just

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
```

On my PC your second line gives back this path that is clearly wrong

```
C:\Users\steve\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\C:\Users\steve\AppData.....
                                                      ^^^^^
```

So a full fix of your code should be as this

```
string mozillaProfilePath = Path.Combine(
  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), 
                            "Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles");

string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(mozillaProfilePath);
if(dirs.Length > 0)
{
    string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(dirs[0]);
    ......
}
```

and, if your process the result directly here, then it is better to use [Directory.EnumeratFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of GetFiles (See remarks in the link posted)

```
.....
if(dirs.Length > 0)
{
    foreach(string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirs[0]))
    {
        .... process each file found ...
    }
}
```

Comment: problem happens again, its because of dot in folder name, how can i fix this?

Comment: I don't understand. What dot? Could you please add a line to your code that prints out the value of _dir_ and show the actual value of that variable?

Comment: i;ve fixed problem which you told about, now it returns: "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\4wrivbme.default"
 As you can see, there is dot, so its main reason of problem.

Comment: the dot shouldn't be a problem, if you try the second line of code like @Steve said, it should work fine. It works fine for me.

Comment: but i did it and it returns me good path but with not supported format

Comment: On my pc is _C:\Users\steve\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ajny07jk.default_ and it is correct. On yours you should have a different default for the final folder but there is no problem if a folder has a dot in its name. If you open the Windows Explorer are you able to see that folder (after enabling the option to show the hidden folders)

Answer (score 1):

Use Path.Combine() instead of string concatenation.